# Excel open xml sdk - Get an empty cell

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

I have excel file that I need to locate a cell at. 
This cell might have attributes like formatting, data validations rules etc. but no value.
I need to retrieve it even if the cell has (currently) no value since I want to maintain all the cell attributes and only set it a value.
Is it possible?

The code:

```
public static Cell GetSpreadsheetCell(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, string addressName)
{
    return worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
            Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not a real a problem. 
Data validation is a side object that store references to cells it applies to. When a formula is inserted the cell always contain some value...